# Tailwind CSS doesn't create classes when rebuilding

Tags: css, command-line-interface, tailwind-css, scoop-installer

I **installed tailwindcss via scoop** and created a new project.

Then i ran via CLI `tailwindcss init` and edited tailwind.config.cjs:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
      "./*.{html}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I created input.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilites;
```

Then created output.css and started the next command:

`tailwindcss -i ./assets/css/input.css -o ./assets/css/output.css --watch`

Every time i edit html.css tailwind css start rebuilding but doens't create the classes i wrote in html file.

How con i solve this?

Thank you

I tried to see some answers here on stackoverflow and but i didn't find any solution to my problem.

Comment: for who see this: import each tailwind layer like this : "@import "taliwndcss/base". It will work

Answer (score 0):

My content section was wrong in the tailwind.config.js file.

One thing I did was change " to ' (I don't think this was the issue but I did change this).
The other thing was to make sure the locations for my files were correct. For example I have an index.html file inside my public folder so this is located at `'./public/index.html'` and then my other files were in a folder, `'./public/pages/**/*/.{html,js}'` but you can also do `'././public/pages/**/*/js'` if you just need js files.